# Which gridcontrol is best to use to display n specific objects and how

Tags: c#, .net, grid, devexpress

I basically need to display the data of two specific objects but I want it to be displayed like a Table.

I have a class with the following Properties: **name**, **age**, **hair color** and **eye color**. I want a Table to show exactly two individuals in a way that the column header (top) shows **name** and the row headers (left) show the other properties. The values are the tables entries, like this:

```
            Peter  Alice
Age         15     27
Hair Color  Brown  Black
Eye Color   Brown  Green
```

From what I tries until now, I think the VGridControl would be the best option. The only 'problem' is, that I want to display the Names (Peter & Alice) as column headers. I could make a Row that has no Title (empty space), and colour the background like the row headers (Age, Hair Color & Eye Color), but I don't think that's a good solution.

I've tried pivotgrid but that is confusing and I don't really get how my data maps onto it.

Is there any intended way for this to work instead of using a workaround like I described?

Comment: Welcome.  _"Which xxx [is] best to use"_ is subject to opinion and sadly off-topic for SO. [ask].  Wishing you well

Comment: I think that PivotGrid is exactly what you want and you should dedicate time to learning more about how to use it